# Does 'hence' (thus, therefore) need a comma after it?

Tags: article-writing

In mathematical papers, when "hence" is placed at the beginning of a sentence, I have observed that some authors use a comma while others do not. The same issue can arise with "therefore" or "thus" as well.

For example:

- **Hence,** by Lemma 5.2, $G$ has at most $3c+ 3n− 8$ triangles, where $c$ is the number of crossings of $ϕ$. ([Counting cliques in 1-planar graphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669822001500))
- Assume first that $t$ has at least two incident uncrossed edges in $\Gamma^{\prime}$. It obtains 12 charges from these two edges, and at least $3\left(\operatorname{deg}_G(t)-2\right)$ further charges from the remaining edges that it had in $G$. **Hence** $c(t) \geq 12+3\left(\operatorname{deg}_G(t)-2\right)=3 \operatorname{deg}_G(t)+6$. ([Matchings in 1‐planar graphs with large
  minimum degree](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jgt.22736))
- By $\left[2\right.$, Theorem 2.4.1] $\phi^{\prime}$ and $\phi$ are of the same order and type. **Therefore** we can find $C>0$, depending on $\rho$ and $\alpha$, so that $\left|\phi^{\prime}(z)\right| \leq C e^{\alpha|z|^\rho}$ for all $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$. ([Superposition operators between weighted spaces of analytic functions](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.2989/16073606.2013.779995?journalCode=tqma20)
- Therefore, $G_1$ cannot contain more than six crossings.([1-Planar Lexicographic Products of Graphs](https://%20http://dx.doi.org/10.12988/ams.2015.56439))
- Thus, the natural questions here are:
  For which entire functions $\phi$ do we have $S_\phi\left(\mathcal{H}_1\right) \subset \mathcal{H}_2$ ? When is $S_\phi$ bounded?
- Thus we can suppose that $f_n$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of } $\mathbb{D}$ to a holomorphic function  ([Bounded superposition operators between weighted Banach spaces
  of analytic functions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0096300312012210))

Can both of these approaches be used? Is it just a matter of style, or is adding a comma more accurate? I'm a bit confused because **my text editor keeps suggesting commas after these words.**

I also noticed that Professor West mentioned this issue on his [homepage](https://dwest.web.illinois.edu/grammar.html#conclwds) (see Item 14), but I'm not sure if I correctly understood his point that a comma should be added after "therefore" but not after "hence" and "thus."

> [14] Words of conclusion: "Hence", "Thus", "Therefore" A long proof does not fit in a single sentence; hence often one needs a word to start a
> sentence that states a conclusion. Among the choices are "Therefore",
> "Hence", and "Thus". Purists (and copy editors) desire a comma after
> every such introductory word or phrase (as they do after "Finally",
> "On the other hand", "In 1965", etc.). This can make language overly
> formal.

> Among these choices, I treat "Therefore" as the most formal,
> introducing a major conclusion and hence taking a comma. Because
> "Hence" and "Thus" are single syllables, I use them without commas to
> indicate the flow of argument without making the writing choppy. This
> choice modifies strict English punctuation in the service of
> mathematical understanding. It is not incorrect to put commas after
> all these introductory words, but it enhances mathematical
> communication to omit the commas after short words introducing short
> conclusions that are just a step along the way. Copy editors put in
> the commas, and I insist that they be removed again.

Are there specific guidelines in mathematical papers regarding this matter?

Comment: In your first example, "hence" is followed by a subclause, making a comma more appropriate. But as far as I am aware, it is a matter of taste and style. I agree with the quoted text that using a comma after *every* instance of these words gives an overly formal feel to the text.

Comment: Thank you, I find it quite strange that every time I discuss mathematical writing, some people suggest closing the topic. I can clearly see that this tag is meant for discussing such matters. (Various aspects of writing mathematics such as **style, notation, grammar, frequently used phrases and common mistakes**. Do I miss somthing?

Comment: If discussions are not allowed, then it seems like the tag's description may need to be revised or the tag itself should be removed.

Comment: Well , then the tag should not be present at all. How an article should be written (concerning layout , style , grammar and so on) is a question that cannot be answered mathematically. Discussions are allowed in comments , but not excessive discussions. Such discussions are usually moved into a chatroom.

Comment: Is there a better platform for discussing these topics? Because it involves mathematics, when I go to English Stack Exchange, they suggest coming here for discussions since they say it relates to mathematics. See this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/592251/is-the-sentence-for-every-integer-3k15-written-correctly

Comment: The same as questions about mathematical physics : Which mathematics is used and how , is a matter of physics. Math can only apply what the phycisists give. In fact, English Stack Exchange is the correct site , why do they think it is not ?

Comment: Indeed. That indeed left me puzzled at the time. You can see " That's not English, it's Mathlish." and "This quetion would probably get better answers on one of the math stackexchange sites, where they could also share how to express this in mathematical notation " And there were even some people who agreed.

Comment: **Tangential** to your final quoted paragraph is [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/612401/difference-in-logical-inevitability-between-therefore-thus-hence/612406#comment1552833_612406), which I had to upvote. Reading it, it occurred to me that while laypersons tend to view 'thus' as more formal (or perhaps more final) than 'therefore', mathy types are perhaps less likely subscribe to this framing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first bullet, the two commas function like parentheses, and are necessary.

In the remaining bullets, your `hence/thus/therefore` all begin their sentences, so I typically *prefer* a comma after each one (though not always: I usually omit commas in the sentence “...and therefore...”), but this is a matter of taste (I agree with Sarvaes that this can make a text sound overly formal).

Ultimately it also depends on the desired effect of the sentences and the overall piece of writing, that is, it is also a matter of style/wit.

Comment: Your last paragraph is severely misleading, in my opinion. "Blah blah, therefore blah blah" could be (and usually is) grammatically wrong, because therefore is being used as if it were a conjunction, which it is not. "It is raining, therefore I will bring an umbrella" is ungrammatical. In these instances it is usually correct to precede "therefore" by "and". The same applies to "thus" and "hence".

Comment: Yes, that didn't sound right; thanks for your explanation; I've deleted that paragraph.